# Say Someone and Tell to Someone - Grammatical Explanation

Tags: grammar, definition, error

My friend often makes grammatical mistakes by *adding* "to" when it's not appropriate (**Tell to him**, **ask to him**...) or *removing* "to" when it should be included (**I said him** - meaning I told him).

I searched the internet for **a definition or grammatical name** for verbs that should be *followed* by "to" and those who shouldn't. I only found explanations about transitive and intransitive verbs, and direct and indirect objects but they don't seem to be related to the issue at hand.

Is there a rule for this type of structures (when to use "to" between a verb and its object and when not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not general rules. There are various patterns, but you cannot generally predict which verbs fit into which patterns.

*Say* is a transitive verb where the object (the utterance) is normally obligatory:

> I said it.

> You must say the words.

but not

> *He said.

(Because what is said can be quoted words, the direct object can precede, in a way that is not normal for other verbs:

> He said "I'll do it". *or* "I'll do it", he said. )

Like many verbs, *say* can take a *to* phrase, specifying who the words are said to:

> He said it to me.

> Say "I'll do it" to her.

This is not an essential argument of *say*, and you cannot use the special "ditransitive" syntax, as you can for *give*:

> I gave the cake to John = I gave John the cake.

> I said the words to John. *but not* *I said John the words.

*Tell* has two different possible patterns.

One use is **ditransitive**, with a direct object for the message, and an indirect object for the person told:

> She told a story to the children = She told the children a story.

(The same two patterns as *give*).

but it can also be used without the message, in which case it is transitive, with the person being the direct object:

> She told him *but not* *She told to him.

In summary

*Say* must have an object (the words said, which can precede if they are directly quoted), and it may have a *to* phrase; if it does, the *to* is obligatory.

*Tell* may have one or two objects. If it has only one, the object is the person told, and *to* is not allowed.
If *tell* has two objects, then the message is direct, and the person indirect. The indirect object needs *to* unless it precedes the direct object (same pattern as *give*).

Comment: There are general rules. There's more than one way to use those verbs, but to say there are no rules is incorrect and discouraging.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, the rules for these verbs are pretty simple. Your friend just has to learn the grammar structure of each of these *reporting verbs*, and there aren't many.

**These grammar structures below (in [brackets]) don't include every correct way to use these verbs**, but they include the most natural ways, and are always going to be correct.

*[ "say" + something ]* (direct speech, no indirect object)

> She said, "Come with me".

*[ "say" (+ "to" + someone) + "that" + clause ]* (indirect speech)

> She said (to Harry) that his shirt was inside-out.

*[ "tell" + someone (something) ]* (give information; indirect speech)

> I told her that I wasn't interested.

*[ "tell" + someone + "to" + infinitive ]* (give instructions or an order)

> They told me to improve my writing skills and apply again in three months.

*[ "ask" (+ someone) (+ something) ]* (ask for information; direct or indirect speech)

> He asked Sally, "What's your last class on Tuesday?"
> He asked Sally what her last class on Tuesday was.

*[ "ask" + someone + "to" + infinitive ]* (give instructions or an order)

> I asked him to wash the floor.